# Why is my Postgres cursor running out of memory?

Tags: java, postgresql, out-of-memory, database-cursor

I have a huge table that I'm trying to stream out to a file.  However it seems that no matter what I try, Postgres is trying to pull all the data at once and running out of memory.  I've read *many* posts here and elsewhere and I think I'm doing this "right", so why do I keep running out of memory?

Here's my code:

```
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPassword);

        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        conn.setReadOnly(true);

        Statement ps = conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, 
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);

        ps.setFetchSize(10);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM BIGTABLE "
             + "WHERE '20150401' BETWEEN startdate AND enddate";

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sql);

        writeResultSet(os, rs);
```

The code never gets past the query execution before running out of memory.

In case it matters, this is happening in a separate thread while streaming to an open ZipOutputStream.  At this point, one item has already been streamed out and I never get to the point where I can stream out this table.

I'm working with Postgres 9.3.5, and currently limiting the VM to 128MB for testing.  While I could increase the heap size, I still think I shouldn't be running into this issue.

[jsyk, I've stripped out try/catch blocks and the like for clarity.]

Comment: 128MB is a very small amount of memory and a large query could definitely exceed Java's memory limit. Have you tried allocating more memory? Additionally, can you please post the full error message.

Comment: @adam OP is using a small memory limit to have the test fail quicker. His intention is to achieve O(1) space requirement and a smaller heap limit will be more sensitive to detect O(n) space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT
```

This setting asks for a holdable cursor, which is implemented client-side for Postgresql. Postgresql itself does not support native holdable cursors over the protocol used by JDBC (the Frontend/Backend protocol). Related post:

http://postgresql.nabble.com/New-significance-of-holdable-result-sets-in-Java-8-td5826656.html

Note also that even the native holdable cursor has O(n) space requirement, but it will allocate in on disk.

However, by looking at your code I see no reason why you would need a holdable cursor.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the holdable cursor.  I had been getting an error where it sounded like my connection was closing, so I turned that on.  But I just removed it and I am no longer running out of memory!  It's actually looking very memory-healthy.

I'm wondering whether the problem I was having before was due to using a PreparedStatement instead of a simple Statement.  Anyone know?  Regardless, I'm over this hurdle.  Thanks for the insight, Marko!